# Calculate Cosine Similarity between Two Vectors (Values in Rows) in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, cosine-similarity

This is how my data set looks like in a Pandas Dataframe structure:

```
df

index id time var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
1     1  1    .    .    .    .    .
2     1  2    1    1    2    2    3
3     1  3    .    .    .    .    .
4     1  4    1    3    1    2    6
5     1  5    .    .    .    .    .
6     2  1    2    1    3    3    2
7     2  2    .    .    .    .    .  
8     2  3    .    .    .    .    .
9     2  4    4    3    1    2    3
...
```

Where there are multiple records for each id over time with some other columns which will be used to calculate Cosine Similarity(CS).

I searched for some resources so that I can apply CS calculation in my context but failed to find a good one.

What I want to do is I want to calculate a CS which will be derived as one single value between index 2 vector (1,1,2,2,3) and index 4 vector(1,3,1,2,6). At the same time, I also need to avoid missing rows to do this. Every id group has only two vectors.

 In the same way for the id 2, such as CS between (2,1,3,3,2) and (4,3,1,2,3).

Below code is what I have thought that could be applied in my case which will generate CS as a single value:

```
import scipy
from scipy import spatial
vector1 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
vector2 = [1, 3, 1, 2, 6]

cosine_similarity = 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(vector1, vector2)
print (cosine_similarity)

Output: 0.8994895926845297
```

What would be a good way to address this while I account for a few of the constraints?
Thank you.